# WPF - Configure custom event to trigger begin storyboard on user control

Tags: wpf, canvas, storyboard, eventtrigger, elementhost

I hope someone is able to assist here, either to advise how to fix what I have or to suggest a better way of achieving what I'm after.

I have a simple custom control on which I want to be able to start/stop/pause/resume an opacity animation.  I've looked at various solutions and figured that using `EventTrigger` with a custom `RoutedEvent` was the way forward. I can get the following to work with a standard event (eg `MouseDown`) but am unable to get my custom event to start the storyboard.

I tried raising the event in the constructor prior to doing it in a loaded event, but neither makes any difference.

I don't think it has any relevant impact but this is also being hosted in an `ElementHost` for winforms.

**xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Fraxinus.BedManagement.WpfControls.FraxIconX"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Fraxinus.BedManagement.WpfControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="16" d:DesignWidth="16"
             Loaded="FraxIconX_Loaded">
    <!--Height="16" Width="16" Background="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Control}, AncestorLevel=1}}" -->
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Border x:Key="RoundedBorderMask" Name="iconBorder" CornerRadius="4" Background="White" BorderThickness="2" Height="16" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Border BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="4" Height="16" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <local:FraxCanvas x:Name="fraxCanvas" Height="16" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <local:FraxCanvas.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" GradientStops="{Binding GradientStops}" />
            </local:FraxCanvas.Background>
            <local:FraxCanvas.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:FraxCanvas.OnStartStoryboard" SourceName="fraxCanvas">
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="storyboard">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0.25" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever"></DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </local:FraxCanvas.Triggers>
            <local:FraxCanvas.OpacityMask>
                <!--https://wpf.2000things.com/2012/05/11/556-clipping-to-a-border-using-an-opacity-mask/-->
                <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource RoundedBorderMask}"></VisualBrush>
            </local:FraxCanvas.OpacityMask>
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Width="16" Source="{DynamicResource BitmapClockPng}" />
        </local:FraxCanvas>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

**Code behind**

```
    public partial class FraxIconX : UserControl
    {

        public GradientStopCollection GradientStops { get; set; }

        public FraxIconX() { }

        public FraxIconX(Color backColour, int width = 16, int height = 16)
        {
            Width = width;
            Height = height;
            GradientStops = new GradientStopCollection { new GradientStop(Colors.AliceBlue, 0.0), new GradientStop(Colors.Navy, 1.0) };
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(backColour);
            DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void FraxIconX_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(FraxCanvas.StartStoryboardEvent));
        }
    }
```

**FraxCanvas:**

```
    public class FraxCanvas : Canvas
    {
        public static readonly RoutedEvent StartStoryboardEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("OnStartStoryboard", RoutingStrategy.Tunnel, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(FraxCanvas));

        public event RoutedEventHandler OnStartStoryboard
        {
            add
            {
                this.AddHandler(StartStoryboardEvent, value);
            }

            remove
            {
                this.RemoveHandler(StartStoryboardEvent, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues.

1. You are listening exclusively to `EventTrigger.SourceName="fraxCanvas"`, but the event is raised somewhere else (parent `UserControl`).
   `EventTrigger.SourceName` is a filter property, which allows to
   exclusively handle a Routed Event of a specific element. If you don't set `EventTrigger.SourceName`,
   the trigger will handle the specified event, no matter the
   source.
2. The Routed Event will never reach the `FraxCanvas` element, because a parent raised it.
   `RoutingStrategy.Bubble`: event travels from *event source*, the `FraxIconX` element,  to the
   visual tree root e.g., `Window`.
   `RoutingStrategy.Tunnel`: event travels from the tree root e.g., `Window` and **stops** at the *event source*, the `FraxIconX` element.

The solution is to remove the `EventTrigger.SourceName` attribute and move the trigger to the event source (the `UserControl`) or to any of the event source's parent element:

```
<UserControl>    
  <UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:FraxCanvas.OnStartStoryboard">
      <BeginStoryboard x:Name="storyboard">
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="fraxCanvas" 
                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                           From="1" To="0.25" />
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </UserControl.Triggers>

  <Border>
    <FraxCanvas x:Name="fraxCanvas" />
  </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Fantastic, that works a treat. Thank you very much for both the solution and improving my understanding. I've upvoted but it doesn't show due to my insufficient reputation. That was a big dose of paracetamol to my headache :-)